# can I make an two-dimension array which its element is List

Tags: java, arrays

as the title says I want to make an two-dimension array like below:

```
List<List<Integer>>[][] dp = new LinkedList<List<Integer>>[3][3];
```

then the compiler dont permit me do that.
It is easy to think about use a class to encapsulate it. Like this:

```
class Node{
    List<List<Integer>> list = ...;
}
Node[][] nodes = new Node[3][3];
```

but I want to know are there exist more simpler way to achieve this.

Comment: Can you tell us what your actual need is for this data structure?

Comment: Question can be simplified to List<Integer>[] dp = new LinkedList<Integer>[3];

Comment: @Tim just for curiosity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ll have to live with this ugly cast if you want simplicity:

```
List<List<Integer>>[][] dp = (LinkedList<List<Integer>>[][]) new Object[3][3];
```

In java, we can't create generic arrays. This is a long discussion, and I encourage you to read about it.

Briefly, java knows nothing about generics - it just checks for type safety at compile time, and then "translates" the generics to plain `Object`

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to create a class that extends the `List`, like this:

```
private static class ListOfList extends LinkedList<List<Integer>> {}
```

Than,

```
ListOfList[][] dp = new ListOfList[3][3];
```

---

Note that I used a nested class, so it will go inside your main class.